# How to make animation for all captions in flexslider using animate.css

Tags: css, animation, flexslider, captions, animate.css

I wanna make some animations for every caption in flexslider using css3 animation.

tried using inview.js and pure css3 animation it's animating the first slide on page load only, Without the other slides.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle for the issue? It helps in understanding the problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This github pull request can fit my needs

https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/pull/865